# Leaf Shinobi vest colours

Tags: naruto

I am curious to know why some leaf shinobi's vest colours are green and some are dark green. For example, Shikaku wears a dark green vest and Kakashi wears green. Are dark green vests considered elite shinobi? Wouldn't Kakashi be considered elite? Does it signify something about that particular shinobi?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably the vest worn by Shikaku is just old or something.

Comment: From a character design perspective, the creators would have gone for a design and color which will be easily identified by anyone watching Naruto, even after a break. So identification of which village the characters belong to is the important aspect in choosing colors and designs.

Comment: @Dragon yeah there is a difference.

Comment: @IE5Master Sorry if i'm wrong but do you mind sending me a link of where you see them as different colors please

Comment: @Dragon https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjz6_KeufrMAhUBeD4KHb41BUIQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnaruto.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FShikaku_Nara&psig=AFQjCNFdPt0S9nvmgQAfsbJ1IoMcDmYcuw&ust=1464445093867143

Comment: @Dragon in the wikia, they describe him wearing a dark green flak jacket

Comment: @IE5Master  sorry about my stupid information and comment, i didn't realize of the different colors, i thought it was just the animation style.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little bit of search about outfits in Naruto series, only 2 ninjas had a dark green outfit.

[Shikaku](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shikaku) and [Asuma](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Asuma_Sarutobi). If you check both of their profiles in Naruto wikia, nothing is being said about the color.

This is a peace from Asuma description:

> *His clothing consisted of the standard [Konoha](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Konohagakure) ninja uniform with the
>   sleeves rolled up half way, flak jacket, regular shinobi sandals and
>   forehead protector. He also wore a sash that had the kanji for "Fire"
>   (火) marked on it around his waist, a pair of black bangles, and
>   bandages wrapped around the arms of his sleeves.*

Also [the flak jacket](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flak_Jacket), for [Konohagakure](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Konohagakure) it's only one, there is no other jacket that the [Jōnins](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/J%C5%8Dnin) wear.

So I asume it has to do mostly with Shikaku that he was the [Jōnin Commander](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/J%C5%8Dnin_Commander), so we can understand the difference between him and the other [Jōnins](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/J%C5%8Dnin).

So to summarize, it's just a speculation about all this. But there are no evidence about these colours. Maybe in a Naruto SBS there is an explanation, about this, which I can't find.

Comment: I can understand the colour being different for Shikaku if he was the Jonin Commander. What about Asuma though?

Comment: Maybe because he was the son of the 3rd? I don't know it's just an assumption

Comment: that is what i was thinking

Answer (score 0):

It's not overtly mentioned, but the difference in jonin vests color does actually mean something in the leaf village. Shinobi with Darker tone green vests are jonin platoon leaders (Not to be mixed with team leaders such as Kakashi or Guy). Also, it's not just Asuma and Shikaku, it's around 10 other Shinobi that appeared on screen like Raido and Aoba (3rd hokage bodygards), Genma (Chonin exam practor) , Shisui (Uchiha), Inoichi (Ino's father), Tsume (Kib's mother), Hiyashi (Hyuga), and others that I don't recall their names or they were not significant enough to be mentioned by name.